# How to select a group of columns related to another column in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, group-by, having

I have a MySQL table containing users, files and file ages as shown below.

| Users | Files | File age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 42 |
| A | 2 | 17 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 4 | 85 |
| B | 5 | 73 |
| B | 6 | 11 |
| C | 7 | 6 |
| C | 8 | 9 |
| C | 9 | 3 |

Now I need to select the names of all files of a specific user having an age larger 10. Users with no or only some files with an age > 10 shall not be selected.

With the example from above the result should be:

| Users | Files | File age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 4 | 85 |
| B | 5 | 73 |
| B | 6 | 11 |

I assume that the SQL ALL operator together with a sub query is my friend, but I do not get satisfying results here. Would be therefore happy to hear some ideas.

Thanks a lot!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

One possibility is a `left join` and then check for `null`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2
  ON t1.users = t2.users AND t2.fileage <= 10
WHERE t2.fileage IS NULL
```

Another possibility is using `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT *
  FROM mytable t2
  WHERE t1.users = t2.users AND t2.fileage <= 10
 )
```

Another possibility is using `< ALL` (as you mentioned in the question):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE 10 <= ALL
 (
  SELECT fileage
  FROM mytable t2
  WHERE t2.users = t1.users
 )
```

You can see a [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/36cMIcAl).

I've edited my answer to use `<=` instead of just `<` since I had your boundary condition wrong.